# Llevar información de un formulario a php en background para actualizar un registro

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, json

Con la información del formulario , realizo la consulta en la misma página para actualizar el valor del campo "estado".
No sé muy bien como funciona ajax, si que he usado otras veces json para enviar información de php a javascript, todo este proceso se realizaría en background sin cambiar de página.

Gracias por la ayuda

```html
<form action="Actualizar Estado.php" method="POST">
                    <div class="row">
                        
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
                            <div style="padding-left:80px;">
                            <input type="text" name="idreserva" class="form-control" placeholder="  ¿Id de Reserva?" >
                        </div>
                           <div style="padding-left:80px"> 
                        <select  name="estado" class="form-control" >
                                <option value="nada" >¿Estado del Pedido?</option>
                                <option value="completo">Completado</option>
                                <option value="anulado">Anulado</option>
                            </select>
                        <p></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div style="padding-left:140px" >
                            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-xl-4 py-xl-3"><span></span> Cambiar Estado</button>

<?php

$consulta= "SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE idpedido='$subs_idreserva';";

$resultado = mysqli_query( $conexion, $consulta ) or die ( "Error en la Realización de la Búsqueda");


echo "<table borde='2'>";
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<th>Idpedido</th>";
 echo "<th>Pedido</th>";
 echo "<th>Estado</th>";
 echo "</tr>";
 // Bucle while que recorre cada registro y muestra cada campo en la tabla.
 while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ))
 {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $columna['idpedido'] . "</td><td>" . $columna['pedido'] . "</td><td>" . $columna['estado']. "</td>"; 
  echo "</tr>";
 } 
 echo "</table>"; // Fin de la tabla
    mysqli_close( $conexion );
   ?>
```

Comment: Puedes ser más minucioso en tu explicación, que error genera, qué resultado esperas, o sólo es que no sabes usar AJAX? Edita tu pregunta para que se entienda mejor, gracias.

Comment: No se hacerlo, se que tiene que ser por ajax

Comment: Quiero actualizar el estado por el del formulario en background, sin recargar la página

Comment: estas usando jquery?

Comment: Entonces requieres hacer una actualización en el campo `estado` de tu BD? dependiendo que seleccione en el `<select>`?

Answer (score 0):

para usar ajax debes poner tu código PHP en otro script ya que ajax hace un request a la url que tu le proporciones, lo que debes hacer es tomar los datos del formulario algo como esto.

```
 <form action="Actualizar Estado.php" method="POST">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
                        <div style="padding-left:80px;">
                        <input type="text" name="idreserva" class="form-control" placeholder="  ¿Id de Reserva?" >
                    </div>
                       <div style="padding-left:80px"> 
                    <select  name="estado" class="form-control" >
                            <option value="nada" >¿Estado del Pedido?</option>
                            <option value="completo">Completado</option>
                            <option value="anulado">Anulado</option>
                        </select>
                    <p></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div style="padding-left:140px" >
                        <button onclick="cambiarEstado()" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-xl-4 py-xl-3"><span></span> Cambiar Estado</button>
 </form> <!-- no olvides cerrar el formulario --->

 <script>

        cambiarEstado() {
             var form = document.querySelector('form');
             var data = new FormData(form);

             var params = typeof data == 'string' ? data : Object.keys(data).map(
        function(k){ return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k]) }
    ).join('&');

             // example request
             getAjax('scriptPHPParaUpdate.php', params);
        }

        function getAjax(url, params) {
            var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new               ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            xhr.open('POST', url);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState>3 && xhr.status==200)
                    success(xhr.responseText);
                else 
                    error(xhr.responseText);
            };
          xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
          xhr.send(params);
          return xhr;
   }

   error(response) {
        console.log(response);
   }

   function success(response) {
        console.log(response);
   }

 </script>
```

Ahora en el script php donde recibiras el request pones tu código.

El código es para porderte guiar sobre lo que debes hacer, lo que estaría haciendo es tomar los datos del formulario y enviarlos en un request POST con ajax hacia tu script php donde tomaras la información del formulario y actualizarás.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos

Comment: Pero al llamar al .php mediante ajax y en este realizar el UPDATE en la base de datos , ¿se puede actualizar el estado en la misma página, sin recargarla?

Comment: ¿O ,pasar el nuevo estado al mismo php de la página mediante json para que vuelva a realizar la consulta?

Comment: Es correcto, puedes hacer eso con javascript, por eso te puse la función success cuando la respuesta que te devuelve el script que hace el update fue exitosa, dentro de esa función pones el nuevo estado usando javascript. Lo que estarías haciendo es un SPA (Single page application) ya que darías la impresión de que es una aplicación de escritorio por que no recargas la pagina de todo se encarga ajax.